# How to export pdf table data into csv?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pdf-reader

I am using Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2, Gem: 'pdf-reader'.

My application will read pdf file which has table-data and it exports into CSV which i have already done. When i match result with table header and table content, they are in wrong position, yes because pdf table is not a actual table, we need to write some extra logic behind this which I am asking for.

marks.pdf has content similar as shown below

School Name: ABC

Program: MicroBiology   Year: Second

| Roll No    | Math     |
|----------- |--------  |
1000001      |  65
|----------- |--------  |

Any help would be appreciated.

Working code which reads PDF and export to CSV is given below

```
class ExportToCsv
  # method useful to export pdf to csv
  def convert_to_csv
    pdf_reader = PDF::Reader.new("public/marks.pdf")
     csv = CSV.open("output100.tsv","wb", {:col_sep => "\t"})
      data_header = ""
      pdf_reader.pages.each do |page|
         page.text.each_line do |line|
            # line with characters
            if /^[a-z|\s]*$/i=~line
              data_header = line.strip
            else
              # line with number
              data_row = line.split(/[0-9]/).first     
              csv_line = line.sub(data_row,'').strip.split(/[\(|\)]/)
              csv_line.unshift(data_row).unshift(data_header)
              csv << csv_line
            end
          end
        end
     end
  end
```

I am not able to attach original pdf here because of security, sorry for that. You can generate the pdf as per below screenshot.

The screen of pdf is given below:
[image]

The screen of generated Csv is given below:
[image]

Desired pdf should be like below image
[image]

Comment: If you could share a sample pdf and desired CSV, it could help to understand  the requirement better.

Comment: @RohitJangid: You can see the update now!